# I would like to take an online Fraud course and need help finding it?

Tags: usaidopen

I would like to take an online Fraud course and need help finding it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are USAID staff, I recommend signing into the agency-only site https://pages.usaid.gov/ and navigating to USAID University.  I see several fraud related courses listed.
Best,
Data Services Team